Pi 4 overheating
i have recently borrowed a pi4 b from a friend as i wanted to install retro pi for an arcade machine i have, but when i plug it in it gets super hot real fast i work with ovens at work so i am relatively good with heat on my hands but this is too hot to touch and gets to that heat in 30sec - 1 min.
I have tried plugging in without the SD card also and the same thing happens.
I am using an Anker charging station that will supply what the plugged in item needs which i believe is shown by the solid red light that i see?
This is all very new to me and like i say it's not even mine so hopefully i can find the issue before i have to replace it.
Thanks.

Anker charging station that will supply what the plugged in item needs ... what does that mean? ... how is the charging station determining what the RPi needs? ... the RPi is not a battery

As far as i know its built in circitry determins the power required. The light is solid red though, which, from what i have read means it is getting the correct power?

it is unclear what you are using to power the RPi ... you said that it is a battery charger ... you need a power supply

The Pi is probably dead (getting hot fast is a symptom of a dead Pi).  At a guess the Pi was supplied with more than 5 volts.

I have spoken to my electrical engineer friend and he had a look at what i used, he said that definatly wouldn't have killed it, but he also said it might not stable power to constantly deliver the correct amount. I have ordered a psu which will come tomorrow and see what happens.

Did your friend lend you a working pi? Is it working now? If the answer to those questions is yes and no, then you owe your friend a new Pi

Thanks, i notice you can buy different RAM configurations, how do i tell which he gave me? the RAM chip says SEC 946

The Pi4 cannot negotiate power, Power sources SHOULD provide 5±0.25 V.
The MxL7704 PMIC (used on Pi4) states Input voltage range: 4.0 V to 5.5 V.
There are 2 ways to kill a Pi - provide excess voltage (above 5.5 V) or shorting the 5 V pin (pin2) to 3.3 V pin (pin1).
To verify if the power circuitry is working measure the voltage on pins 1 & 2 being careful to ensure that whatever you are using to measure does NOT contact (even momentarily) any other pin.
If 3.3 V is not present on pin 1 the Pi is dead.

Thanks for the info, well a proper psu has arrived today i plugged it in, same thing started getting hot fast, i measured with a multimeter and it was reading 2v i guess that means it is dead?

Also how can i tell what RAM config the board has, i have tried looking on the net and cant match the numbers to anything online SEC946, K4FBE3D, 4HMM6CJ and has like a qr code type thing on it.
